# SQL join between 3 tables with empty rows

Tags: sql, join

I need to save language translations for phrases. I have created 3 tables, one for phrases, one for languages and one for translations with the following details:

1. Language - name and id.
2. phrase - name and id.
3. translation - id, translation, fk_language and fk_phrase.

How do I create a query when I get all the phrases that exist, as well as all the translations for a particular language. If there are no translations, I still want all the phrases to be there.
The web page has a dropdown to select a language, and then enter the translation for all the phrases and then save all the translations with one save button.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `left join`:

```
select p.*, t.*
from phrases p left join
     (translations t join
      languages t
      on t.fk_language = l.id and l.language = 'XXX'
     )
     on t.fk_phrase = p.id ;
```

This is one of those fun cases where using parentheses in the `FROM` clause is a reasonable way of writing the query.